# If everything in a programming language is an expression, would it be refferentially transparent?

Tags: programming-languages, expression, side-effects, referential-transparency

I read somewhere, although I could not find it after *much* searching, that there was some guy who proposed to create a new programming language, which would be *completely* referentially transparent where everything is an expression.

Some questions about referential transparency indicate that certain languages such as Ruby and Perl have *almost* everything as an expression.

**Is this possible/does it exist?**

If I understand this correctly, if a programming language is completely referentially transparent, doesn't this mean there would be no side effects at all, and **is it possible to have a complete programming language without side effects?**

**And the main question of the title, if the goal were to create a completely referentially transparent programming language, would it go without saying that everything would be an expression?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by expression we understand anything that returns a value, a computation that is not an expression must not return value, and by referential transparency can be safely removed. So yes, referential transparency requires that everything is an expression.

But, everything being an expression does not imply that there can be no side effects. For example in the C language there are many expressions that have side effects: take any expression involving the increment and decrement operators ++ and --.

There are a few programming languages with no side effects. Haskell is the most widely used. It uses a clever trick called monads to resolve situations that require modification of state. For example, to print "Hello" on the screen, Haskell doesn't modify the existing universe into one where the word appears on the screen; it creates and returns *a new universe* where the word is on the screen.

Comment: I've heard of Haskell but didn't know it was like this. Could we say that `x++` in C is an expression, but whos parts are not all expression and there is some statement in the _grammer_ that forms part of the `++` operator? Although this is probably 'splitting hairs'.

Comment: I think all that matters is if you call `x++` an expression or not. If you want to define "expression" as "computation that returns a value has *and* produces no side effects" then sure, if everything being an expression implies referential transparency, but then you need a new word for computations that return values and may or may not produce side effects.

Comment: [What is referential transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210835/ddg#9859966)  - / - [As you might know, the term "referentially transparent" means that the value of expression can depend only on the values of its parts, and not on any other facts about them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847918/134044)

Comment: The poet Hoha dreamed he was a butterfly and then awoke and said "Am I a man who dreamed he was a butterfly or a butterfly dreaming he is a man?" / "Really? And which was he?" / "What? Well... who knows?" / "How did he write his poems?" / "With a brush, of course." / "He didn't flap around making information-rich patterns in the air or laying eggs in patterns on cabbage leaves?" / "No one ever mentioned it." / "Then he was probably a man." - Terry Pratchett "Thief of Time"

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have a complete programming language without side effects. Take a look at lisp, haskell or many other functional languages. I believe these are all pretty good examples of what you are thinking of.