# Scala: don't return same element in each cycle

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I have a Scala list with the following elements:

```
Worker("W1", "Worker 1", List(Office 1, Office 2))
Worker("W2", "Worker 2", List(Office 1, Office 3, Office 4, Office 5))
Worker("W3", "Worker 3", List(Office 3, Office 5))
Worker("W4", "Worker 4", List(Office 2, Office 4))
```

And I have this function:

```
def setOffice(office: Office.Office, totalWorkers: List[Worker]): Worker = {
      totalWorkers.find(_.offices.contains(office)).getOrElse(null) }
}
```

It is inside a cycle and is called 3 times in each loop of the cycle (not a functional approach but that is not important in this case).

I want the function to return the first element `Worker` that has `office` in it's list and this function does just that, **however** I want the function to return different results in each cycle and I am not succeeding in trying to do so.

For example, if in one cycle the function is called the 3 times with this parameters:

```
setOffice("Office 1", totalWorkers)
setOffice("Office 2", totalWorkers)
setOffice("Office 3", totalWorkers)
```

It returns:

```
Worker 1
Worker 1
Worker 2
```

But I want it to return

```
Worker 1
Worker 4
Worker 2
```

I could do it easily with a variable but I don't want to use `var's`, I want to do it in a functional way.

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you need to alter the workers each time you call this function(by removing the already found office from their list of Office), this goes against the referential transparency component of a functional language: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847818/referential-transparency

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is

```
    def setOffice(office: Office, workers: List[Worker]): (List[Worker], Option[Worker]) =  {
      // Trivial code without optimizations. Just idea.
      val worker = workers.find(_.offices.contains(office))
      (workers.filterNot(worker.contains), worker)
    }

    val (ws1, w1) = setOffice("Office 1", totalWorkers)
    val (ws2, w2) = setOffice("Office 2", ws1)
    val (ws3, w3) = setOffice("Office 3", ws2)
```

If you need for comprehension, traversing of offices list then [State monad](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/datatypes/state.md) could be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Zernike has the right idea with returning a new list. But I think that solution is a bit overzealous in filtering out workers. If I'm understanding correctly, maybe something like this?

```
def setOffice(office: Office, workers: List[Worker]): (Option[Worker], List[Worker]) = {
  val index = workers.indexWhere(_.offices.contains(office))
  if (index == -1) {
    (None, workers)
  } else {
    val (left, x :: right) = offices.splitAt(index)
    (Some(x), left ::: right :+ x)
  }
}
```

This doesn't remove anything from the resulting list, it just moves the found worker to the end so that it won't be the first one found by the next invocation.

You maybe also be able to turn your loop into a fold with this approach.